# Print value at index given by user input in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, indexing, printing

I am very new to programming in Python, this is something that seems so simple, but I just don't seem to be able to get it right.

I have a list of values.
I want to prompt the user for input.
Then print out the value that's at the corresponding index number in the list.

```
myList [0, 1, 20, 30, 40]    
choice = input()    
print (......)
```

If the user inputs 2, I want to print the the value that is at the index 2 (20).  I am unsure of what to put after print.

Comment: What coding language are you talking about?

Comment: Python, sorry, I'm should have probably mentioned that! ha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by accessing the list using the given input by the user.

The input given by the user I assume would be a String, so we need to use `int()` to change it to an integer.

```
print myList[int(choice)]
```

Additionally, you may want to first check the validity of the input supplied; it cannot be less than 0, or more than the length of the list - 1;

```
choice = int(choice)
if (choice < 0 || choice >= len(myList))
   print('Not Valid')
else
   print myList[int(choice)]
```

Comment: Thanks mate! worked fine with () 

else
   print (myList[int(choice)])